# Asp.Net MVC Bundling on Login Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, bundle

I have an Asp.Net MVC site that uses forms authentication and has no 'public' access. Unauthenticated requests redirect to my Login controller. In the View I am referencing css and js files via Bundles. However, when deployed, the requests to these bundles all redirect to the login page with a RedirectUrl parameter. Make sense?

So, how can I get specific bundles to be accessible without authentication being required?

As a poor workaround I know that I can just reference the individual files placed in a public folder - but this circumvents all the minimising benefits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of things you need to do.

First, change the name of the scripts and styles you want to render to be something that doesn't conflict with a folder in your application. So if you have `~/Content/styles` folder, name your style bundle something like `~/Content/styles/css`.

The `/css` at the end of the bundle name is to prevent the request from being treated like a script.

Second, you need to add authorization for the `Content` or whatever you call your bundle path as referenced in your web.config

```
<location path="Content"> <!--or whatever you call your bundle path instead of Content-->
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

This will prevent the forms authentication redirect and serve up your content.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something here, but your answer seems inconsistent. You suggest `~/Content/styles/css` as the bundle URL, but the authorization path example uses `bundles`.

Comment: Edited my example for clarity. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you should be putting these bundles on the Master view page

on the master page you should have something like this:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

in your view just add your scripts like this:

```
@section Scripts{
//put all your scripts here
}
```

you can define a section for stuff you need in the header and do the same for the css.

If this doesn't work you may need to make sure that your bundle names don't conflict with the names of actual paths in your sites, or else the mvc engine will handle the requests rather than serving up your files.

worst case you have to enable anonymous access to your directories in web.config

```
<configuration>
<location path="content">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<location path="scripts">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="?" />
</authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. The 'real' files are accessible without authentication. For instance, ~/Content/style.css will work, but @Styles.Render("~/Content/style") bumps into the authentication routines and is redirected to Login?RedirectUrl=... Does that make sense?